# How to compute the definite integrals of special functions?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, special-functions, contour-integration

How can these integrals be solved:

$${1\over \pi} \int_{0}^{\infty}\left({{\sqrt{x}(a-bx)}\over {x^{3}+(a-bx)^{2}}}\right)\cos(\sqrt{\alpha x}) \exp(-xt)\,\mathrm{d} x, $$

and

$${1\over \pi} \int_{0}^{\infty}\left({{x^2}\over {x^{3}+(a-bx)^{2}}}\right)\sin(\sqrt{\alpha x}) \exp(-xt)\,\mathrm{d} x. $$

Comment: Differentiation under the integral sign does wonders! Check this out: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2006/projects/integratnfeynman.pdf

Comment: @HritikNarayan : Thank you! It looks interesting, I will have a look at it.

Comment: @HritikNarayan are you saying that can work here, or did you throw in a red herring?